# How to update a table in SQLite which already exist on the device?

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I have created a table in SQLite database in my first version of the app. I want to update that database, adding a new table without deleting the previous data. How to do that?

Comment: Did you use Room or SQLiteHelper?

Comment: sorry for the confusion but the question is regarding updating the database

Comment: i have used SQLiteHelper

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to update your database version (if your current version is 1 then increment it to 2)
2. Execute query to create the table in onUpgrade

Follow the example:

```
class YourDbHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION) {
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES)
    }
    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_UPDATE_ENTRIES) //create new table
        onCreate(db)
    }
    override fun onDowngrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion)
    }
    companion object {
        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        const val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
        const val DATABASE_NAME = "YourDb.db"
    }
}
```

Comment: For details: [https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite)